# Angular 2 using ngOnInit to apply style attribute

Tags: javascript, angular

While the code below produces no errors when I inspect the elements, the styles are not applied to the elements with class="circle". Please don't refer me to ngStyle, I want to know why this isn't working.

```
export class PlayersComponent implements OnInit {
        items: any;

        ngOnInit() {

          this.items = document.querySelector('.circle');
          for(var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++){
            if(i % 2 == 0) {
            this.items[i].style.color = '#0000FF';
            }
            else {
              this.items[i].style.color = '#FF0000';
            }
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Manually playing with the DOM like that is not "the angular way". I suspect what you'll want to do in the end is use something along the lines of ngClass or ngStyle to apply the desired styles to the appropriate elements. Can you give us a better idea of your end goal so we can help with suggestions. What's your html look like, what are you trying to accomplish, etc...

Comment: This might be because angular 2 is not bidirectional (two way update elements) like it used to be in angular 1. Having said that, have you tried to debug to actually know if there are any items at that time in ngOnInit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements will not have been rendered yet in OnInit. You would need to use AfterViewInit and also querySelectAll to get all the elements.

```
    export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    items: any;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.items = document.querySelectorAll('.circle');
      for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
          this.items[i].style.color = '#0000FF';
        }
        else {
          this.items[i].style.color = '#FF0000';
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Accessing the DOM in this way is not a good idea in Angular 2 though. This [article](http://angularjs.blogspot.jp/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html) is a good guide to doing things the Angular way.

Answer (score 1):

Like the others have said, manipulating the DOM like that in Angular 2 is not usually the preferred approach.

**But, if you're looking to do this, you should probably call ngAfterViewInit (a lifecycle hook like ngOnInit) to ensure that the DOM elements are present before running your code.**

Another problem could possibly be that you aren't manipulating the right DOM elements, but it's impossible to tell without more information.